# Can powershell do filename expansion?

Tags: powershell

In the unix shells, a command like:

```
echo *.txt
```

prints:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

because the shell performs file name expansion on the `*.txt` arg. Is it possible to achieve the same result with Powershell? Trying:

```
echo *.txt
```

results just in:

```
*.txt
```

Of course, echo is just a silly example. In practice I want to pass all *.txt files to an external command that does not perform file name expansion itself.

## UPDATE

For my purpose, this is what looks best even though it's not  very elegant:

```
D:\cygwin\bin\echo.exe $(dir *.txt)
```

I used the cygwin echo here for testing because the powershell echo cmdlet would format the files as objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that. The command isn't as succinct as bash but the idea is the same. Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt"
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".txt"}

<#Same command as above#>
Get-ChildItem | ? {$_.Extension -eq ".txt"}
```

Or (as Keith Hill pointed out) if you really need them all on the same line:

```
"$(Get-ChildItem *.txt -Name)"
```

Comment: I would go with `Get-ChildItem *.txt -name` or using an alias `ls *.txt -name`.  And if you want the filenames on the same line then `"$(ls *.ps1 -name)"`.

Comment: @KeithHill, I added that in. I'm usually not a fan of utilizing PS aliases though.

Comment: Don't forget the double quotes around that statement.  That's the important bit that creates a string from the array returned by the sub-expression.  The default separator is space but you can change that by using the `$OFS` variable.  Set `$OFS=', '` then run `"$(Get-ChildItem *.txt -Name)"` and you will get comma separated names.